# Active Directory AccountExpiresDate Comparison

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to write a small script to check if an Active Directory `AccountExpirationDate` is expired or if it is active and null. It seems I can do one or the other but not both. the `$accexpoutput` is just to remove whitespace when printing to the screen. Here is my current script

```
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Input Username"
$currdate = Get-Date
$accexp = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like $username' | Select -ExpandProperty AccountExpirationDate
$accexpoutput = (Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like $username'  -Properties AccountExpirationDate | Format-list AccountExpirationDate | Out-String).trim()

if($accexp -gt $currdate -or !$accexp){write-host $accexpoutput $currdate -ForegroundColor Blue -BackgroundColor Green}

else {Write-Host $accexpoutput $currdate -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black}
```

Any tips or help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$accexp` is missing `-Properties AccountExpirationDate`.

Comment: wow how did I miss that. Thank you

Comment: I appreciate it, @AdminOfThings.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you may use the following:

```
$accexp = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like $username' -Properties AccountExpirationDate |
    Select -ExpandProperty AccountExpirationDate
```

**Explanation:**

By default, `ADUser` objects returned by [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) have a default property set. Any properties not in the default set must either be explicitly passed into or represented by `*` in the `-Properties` parameter.

Multiple non-default properties can be retrieved using the syntax `-Properties Property1,property2,property3` since `-Properties` accepts an array.

Specifically passing a set of properties into `-Properties` will not suppress the default property output. You will need to use some other filtering mechanic like `Select-Object` if you only want to see a specific set of properties.

Using `-Properties *` is not recommended for most cases because of the extra resources required to query superfluous properties. Since you only want one extra property in your case, you should only pass that property into the parameter.

You can view [Active Directory Default and Extended Properties](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx), provided by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0), to see the extended and default properties list. Note that not all properties are considered default or extended. You can retrieve those non-default and non-extended properties by their LDAP display name using `-Properties`.